# How to echo alternatively 2 values on every refresh?

Tags: php, variables, echo

I'm writing PHP code and I have two variables `$var1` and `$var2`. I want a method that helps me to display alternatively on every refresh one of the two values.

For example:

On the first load of page it must display: `echo $var1`

On the first refresh of page it must display: `echo $var2`

On the second refresh of page it must display: `echo $var1`

On the third refresh of page it must display: `echo $var2`

etc...

Comment: Show the code that you already have. So that we can help you. This is not a code-request-community.

Comment: i have a code that display the value randomly not alternatively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can use sessions.

```
<?php

session_start();

$a = 1;
$b = 2;

if(!isset($_SESSION['variable'])){
      $_SESSION['variable'] = true;
}

if($_SESSION['variable']){
      echo $a;
}else{
      echo $b;
}

$_SESSION['variable'] = !$_SESSION['variable'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that what i realy need but you forgot  a brackeat on 8th line :)

Comment: Correction : 
if(!isset($_SESSION['variable'])){

Comment: Sorry, i wrote it at night =]

Answer (score 0):

Counting reloads and saving counter to session (https://github.com/Waldz/Examples/blob/master/session/session_counter.php)

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['timesPageReloaded'])) {
    $_SESSION['timesPageReloaded'] = 1;
}

if ($_SESSION['timesPageReloaded']%2 == 1) {
    echo 'VAR1 (odd reload)';
} else {
    echo 'VAR2 (even reload)';
}

$_SESSION['timesPageReloaded']++;
```